# This app isn't supported by the version of exchange server that your account connects to

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I have developed an office addin which works fine in Office 365. When I try to install the same addin (manifest) exchange 2013 on prem I get the above error.

[image: exchange 2013 error]

Answer (score 3):

There is a [known issue](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/issues/1371) in the documentation when it comes to Exchange 2013. While it does support Outlook Web Add-ins, it only supports the 1.1 Requirement Set (Exchange 2016 supports up to 1.3, Exchange Online is currently at 1.6).

Comment: Thank you so much - I couldn't find it documented anywhere, MSFT discusses the client requirement sets but not server requirement sets.